# jquery form validtion empty fields

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

I am trying to make a form validtion using jquery. Basically, what I want is that whenever a user leaves the required field empty, a message shows up next it, informing the user that the field is empty. What I have done so far is this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

    <title>formulier</title>

    <style type="text/css">

        form span{

            color:red;

        }

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

                $(document).on("ready", loaded);

        function loaded(){

            console.log("loaded");


            $('#naam').blur(validate);


            $('#accept').change(checkbox);

            }



            function validate()

            {

        console.log("validate");

      var lengte= $("#naamveld #postcodeveld #huisnummerveld").val();

                console.log(lengte);

                if ($(this) !== '')

                {

                    $(".foutmelding1").text("Required")

                }



                else{

                    $(".foutmelding1").text("Go on")

                }

            }



        function checkbox(){

            if($('input[type=textbox]').is(':checked')){

                console.log('checked'); 

                $('button').removeAttr("disabled");

             }

            else{

                console.log('not checked');

                $('button').attr("disabled", "disabled");

            }

        }



    </script>

</head>



<body>

    <form action="#" method="post">

        <fieldset>

            <legend>

                NAW

            </legend>

            <p>

                <label for="naamveld">Naam: *</label>

                <label for="dhr">

        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="m" id="dhr" />

                    dhr. </label>

        <label for="mevr">

                    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="f" id="mevr" />

                    mevr. </label>

                <input type="text" name="name" id="naamveld" class="verplicht" />

                <span class="foutmelding">&nbsp;</span>

            </p>

            <p>

                <label for="straatveld">Straat:</label>

                <input type="text" name="street"  id="straatveld" />

                <label for="straatveld">Huisnummer: *</label>

                <input type="text" name="huisnummer"  id="huisnummerveld" class="verplicht" />

                <span class="foutmelding">&nbsp;</span>

            </p>

            <p>

                <label for="postcodeveld">Postcode: * </label>

                <input type="text" name="zip" class="verplicht" id="postcodeveld" />

                <label for="stadveld">Stad:</label>

                <input type="text" name="city" class="verplicht" id="stadveld" />

                <span class="foutmelding">&nbsp;</span>

            </p>

        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>

            <legend>

                Contact

            </legend>

            <p>

                <label for="emailveld">Email:

                    <input type="text" name="email" id="emailveld" />

                </label>

            </p>

            <p>

                <label for="telefoonveld">Telefoon:

                    <input type="text" name="phone" id="telefoonveld" />

                </label>

            </p>

            <p>

                <button name="action" value="send" type="submit" >

                    Verstuur

                </button>

            </p>

        </fieldset>

    </form>

</body>
```

Comment: Instead of reinventing the wheel, why don't you use [one of the many available and tested validation libraries](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?hl=en&btnG=Google+Search#hl=en&gs_nf=1&cp=19&gs_id=3f&xhr=t&q=jquery+validation+library&pf=p&biw=1876&bih=963&sclient=psy-ab&oq=jquery+validation+l&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=38d0ddbb4033f53a) available?

Comment: Because this is a homework assignment, and we need to do it from scratch

Comment: What's happening with the indenting?

Comment: [Homework Policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Read about this, jquery validation: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Comment: Algorithm: detect `blur()` [loss of `focus()`] event in the required field, test if the field is empty, and if so, show an error message, usually by changing `visibility/display` property of the hidden error message. If the field is not empty, the error message is hidden from view.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe (using AJAX) :

```
    $('#button').click(function(){
    //encodeURIComponent encode data proprely... and GET val() aka VALUE!!!
    var name = encodeURIComponent($('#name').val());
    var email = encodeURIComponent($('#email').val());
    var message = encodeURIComponent($('#message').val());

    //check is mail VALID
    var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
    //get data inside $_POST['name'] (PHP) and inside +name+ (form id)
    var data = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message;

    //alert(data);

    //if name is empty

    if($('#name').val() == 0){

    $('.info').hide().fadeIn(1000).html('<p style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-size:20px;">Please enter your name!</p>');
    }
    //if name is less than three characters
    else if(name.length < 2){
    $('.info').hide().fadeIn(1000).html('<p style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-size:20px;">Name must be longer than two letters!</p>');

    }
      //if email is empty
    else if ($('#email').val() == 0){
    $('.info').hide().fadeIn(1000).html('<p style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-size:20px;">Please enter Email!</p>');

    }

    //if mail adress is NOT valid
    else if(reg.test(email)==false){
    //alert('please enter valid mail!');
    $('.info').hide().fadeIn(1000).hide().fadeIn(1000).html('<p style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-size:20px;">Please enter VALID Mail!</p>');
    }
    //if mail adress IS VALID 
     if(reg.test($('#email').val()) && $('#name').val()!=''){
     $('.info').hide().fadeIn(1000).html('<p class="thx" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-size:20px;">THX for your mail!</p><span class="success" style="font-weight:bold;text-align:center;font-size:20px;display:none;margin:0 auto">Mail sent successfuly!!</span>');


           $.ajax({
           type:"POST", //php method
           url:'process.php',//where to send data...
           cache:'false',//IE FIX
           data: data, //what will data contain (no SHIT Sherloc...)

           //check is data sent successfuly to process.php
           //success:function(response){
           //alert(response)
           //}

           success: function(){ //on success do something...

           $('.success').delay(2000).fadeIn(1000);

           //alert('THX for your mail!');
           }).error(function(){ //if sucess FAILS!!
           alert('An error occured!!');
           $('.thx').hide();
           });
           } //end if statment for VALID mail


           //return false prevent Redirection
           return false;
           });
```